# Eclipse Ant build Jar from 1 project and move to build path of another project

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse workspace I have 3 projects - 2 dynamic web projects using Tomcat and a data access layer project.  What I want to do is whenever I clean (Project - Clean...) or build the dynamic web projects I want Eclipse / Ant to automatically build the jar from the DAL project and move it into the lib folder of each dynamic web project and add them to the build path.  So far I've added the build.xml to 1 of the dynamic projects and this is what I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="dal-Main" default="CreateJar">
<target name="CreateJar" description="Create Jar file">
    <jar destfile="dal.jar" basedir="." />
    <move file="dal.jar" todir="./WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
</target>
</project>
```

It's kind of working, but for some reason Eclipse is complaining about class not found from that jar.  However, when I add it manually it works fine.  It also only runs this when I go Project - Build Project Argh!!

Comment: This may prove useful, in particular the two highest voted answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985976/refresh-an-eclipse-project-with-ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

First, you can solve your problem with a dependency management tool like ivy or maven with or without nexus easily.

Second, Eclipse cache much as it can. If you change something in the filesystem, e.g. with ant copy or with BASH cp, Eclipse doesn't recognize it, your dependent project build fails. You have to refresh your project or copy the artifact (Jar file) with Eclipse it self. Or you can try to activate the Eclipse/Workspace/Refresh using ... feature, see following  screenshot. These feature needs additional CPU and works different on different OS.

[image: Eclipse Prefs]