# Refresh eclipse workspace after the test suit ends

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng, reporting

I have a maven project for testing. I am using testng plugin. After the test run is complete we get a **test-output** folder in package explorer of eclipse . What i want to do is send the email-able report from withing the "test-output" folder. To do this i need to refresh the work-space after the test run . How should i do it.

If we don't refresh we will get the old test run report on the mail . Thus its necessary to refresh work-space

Comment: there is a way to do some Eclipse related calls with Ant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985976/refresh-an-eclipse-project-with-ant, so maybe you do something similar with Maven.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Couldnt find one with maven , thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse provides a way to automatically refresh resources modified externally:
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh using native hooks or polling.

Not sure if it'll solve your problem cause you can't control the exact instant of refreshing, but it may be worth trying.

Comment: Thankyou @Luis, 1 out of 10 times it works rest time it doesn't because of the fact you stated :)

Comment: more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951785/on-eclipse-what-does-preferences-general-workspace-refresh-using-nati